# Unable to detect version control system for go protobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

Running `go get` on my go project I receive the following error message:

`package code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto: unable to detect version control system for code.google.com/ path`

I have not changed anything, what is going on?

Comment: [code.google.com has been closed](http://google-opensource.blogspot.de/2015/03/farewell-to-google-code.html). You can now find [protobuf on Github](https://github.com/golang/protobuf)

Comment: Which is what the answer indicates. I hit this issue after installing `golang-goprotobuf-dev` on Ubuntu 14.04.1 in response to an error compiling a protobuf to go.

Comment: I wrote this during a review, that's why I didn't see the answer…

Answer (score 1):

The golang protobuf project has moved from [google code](https://code.google.com/p/gogoprotobuf/) to [github](https://github.com/golang/protobuf).

The `protoc` version being used to generate the go code from the protocol buffer definition is out of date and uses the old import.

Install `protoc-gen-go` from github project instructions: https://github.com/golang/protobuf